# git still untracked after add

Tags: git, version-control, commit, addition

Everytime I do git status there is this folder that appears as untracked.

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       src/error/
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Even after doing `git add .`, `git commit -a` the folder at src/error keeps showing up as untracked. Other unstaged files get commited everytime only this folder keeps giving problems. Also git doesnt report any errors. What could be the problem here ?

Comment: Have you tried `git add src/error/` ?

Comment: I tried that it didnt work i have a file in that folder i also tried adding that file directly didn't work also.

Comment: Did you try to add a specific file under src/error ? What do you have in your .gitignore file ?

Comment: Can you show us the command you run and it's output? Also the contents of your .gitignore file would be helpful. Best guess: try using the '-f' flag with git add.

Comment: For this project i am not using the exclude or .gitignore files.

I ran $ git add . -f -v i did not get any output. Then i did git status and i got the same output as in the first message telling me that the folder is untracked.

Comment: @slayerIQ:  Consider answering @strager, @Greg Sexton

Comment: there isn't a git repo or something in that folder is there? what's in the folder?

Comment: @xenoterracide: The fact that git status lists it indicates that there are things that git thinks it should be able to add. @slayerIQ: Why are you running `git commit -a` immediately? Can you show us the output of `git add src/error` and then the output of `git status`, if changed, and the same for `git add -f src/error` (note that those options should be before, not after, the path)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the problem and the solution this is what happened:

First src/error was called src/Error when i changed the case locally the foldername was changed but in git it was still commited as src/Error. Windows is case-insensitive so what i did was remove the folder commit and add it again with the right casing.

Answer (score 1):

Is that the folder empty if so it is normal, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030230/does-git-ignore-empty-folders)

Answer (score 1):

I've tried the following in a Windows 7 console and it worked, i.e. it did not show `\src\error\` as untracked.

```
C:\t>dir
 Volume in drive C is BLAH
 Volume Serial Number is 2ECA-CB88

 Directory of C:\t

10.08.2010  17:56    <DIR>          .
10.08.2010  17:56    <DIR>          ..
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  59'844'902'912 bytes free

C:\t>mkdir .\src\error

C:\t>copy con: .\src\error\text.txt
blah^Z
        1 file(s) copied.

C:\t>git init
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/t/.git/

C:\t>git add .\src\error\*

C:\t>git status
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       new file:   src/error/text.txt
#
```

This doesn't answer your question, but I thought it might help to see a full step-by-step example.