# git-p4 cloned repo contains mixed filename case -- how to fix?

Tags: windows, perforce, case-insensitive, msysgit, git-p4

I imported a large repo using git-p4, and discovered that I have some strangely mixed-case filenames, e.g.:

```
dirA/DIRb/file1.txt
```

and then other files like so:

```
DIRa/dirB/FILE2.txt
```

and so on. These get entered into the repo this way because git-p4 uses fast-import. This causes Git to mysteriously claim that there are untracked directories, which are definitely not untracked, and have no new files in them. I discovered from reading this question:

[git still untracked after add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446929/git-still-untracked-after-add)

and specifically slayerIQ's answer, that this can be fixed by renaming the dirs in question to have the matching case. And indeed, in a few cases where files had only a single case format, this fixed it. But for the mixed up ones like I mentioned above, it does nothing. This sort of listing confirms my suspicions regarding the case:

```
git ls-tree --name-only -r branch
```

I've considered using history rewriting to try to fix it, but that seems awfully heavyweight and I'm a bit hesitant to go there unless I have to (the tree is ~25K files). On the other hand, I do "git status" on a clean tree and get a list of about 35 "untracked" paths. So it's sort of untenable.

I'm able to do a git-p4 clone from scratch if I need to, but I suspect the mixed case paths are coming from Perforce itself. SmartGit doesn't have this problem with the tree, and copying the exact tree to a new repo works fine (since it's added correctly).

Any ideas on how to proceed?

Thanks :)

Comment: I believe this is a bug in git-p4. I tried to fix it here:
https://github.com/larsxschneider/git/commit/75d75def99ad4d260cb45d402e0e7a2dde4b8e28 I proposed the fix to the git mailing list. I'll update this answer when the fix gets accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and tried `git filter-branch --tree-filter "" HEAD` but that didn't do anything. Maybe there is a prettier way to do this with that, that I missed. (My git-fu is weak.)

This is ugly, ugly, ugly, but I found at least one way to do it:

- `git-p4 rebase` to get everything up to date.
- Copy the `.git` to another directory.
- Switch to that new directory and update the tree with `git reset --hard`.
- Delete that shiny `.git` you just copied over. There is now a pristine tree with the latest Perforce check-in.
- `git init` and `git add -A`, then `git commit`, to make an initial check-in on a new tree. For the commit message, imitate git-p4's initial check-in message:

`Initial import of //depot/ from the state at revision #head`

`[git-p4: depot-paths = "//depot/": change = 58840]`

- Of course update 58840 to whatever was your **last** revision before, and your depot path to whatever is appropriate. (Looking at the commit log in the other tree will tell you everything you need to know.)
- `git gc` after that if you don't want things to be terribly slow.

You should now have a basic, non-git-p4 tree. We also need to set up the remote refs. I'm sure there is a clever git way of doing this, but I don't know it, so I will tell you what I did.

- `git log` to find our import revision. Note its SHA ID.
- Look in your original repo's `.git/refs` tree. Copy `.git/refs/remotes` into `<newrepo>/.git/refs`. Edit `refs/remotes/p4/master` to reflect your HEAD's SHA ID.

You should now have a fully functional repo that looks to git-p4 like it checked it out itself, but with consistent casing. Of course you lost your previous local history :( but if you do this early on, it's not as big of a deal.

I'm not sure if the problem comes back over time, if git-p4 continues to use fast-import, but my tree is now showing as clean on `git status` when it's clean.