# Git ignores directories named "temp"

Tags: git, nginx

I've added **nginx** to a git repository, but the apparently very much needed `temp` directory  is never cloned or pulled to other repositories. All the other directories added at the same time are fine, but `temp` fails to appear whether I pull in Windows or Linux.

If I create a new file under `temp`, `git status` lists it as an untracked file, to my understanding meaning the directory isn't ignored. But why isn't it getting pulled?

**Edit:** It seems that the whole `temp` directory can't be staged, no matter what I try. I've tried adding it with the `-f` option and `git add .` but neither adds `temp` or its subdirectories to the staging area. I've tried on multiple machines and different repositories, but the result is always the same:

```
[root@carbon:~/gittest]$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /root/gittest/.git/
[root@carbon:~/gittest]$ mkdir temp
[root@carbon:~/gittest]$ git add temp
[root@carbon:~/gittest]$ git status
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)
```

Comment: pls cehck .gitignore file. May be this folder is listed in the gitignore

Comment: @S.Ali: .gitignore only contains `nbproject`. I also tried to `git add -f temp` and `cd temp; git add .`, but neither has any effect.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does git ignore empty folders?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030230/does-git-ignore-empty-folders)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just realized my mistake: git does not track empty directories. Turns out the directories under `temp` were all empty. After adding blank `.gitignore` files under all of them they were finally added.