# Why can't the folder created by me be committed to GitHub in Android Studio?

Tags: git, android-studio

The following image is a directory structure of a project of Android Studio, the app can be committed to GitHub correctly.

Now I add a folder named MyNewFolder to the structure. I hope to commit the MyNewFolder to  GitHub, so I right-click the folder MyNewFolder and select the menu item Git -> Commit Directory... , but system displays "No changes detedcted", why?

**Image 1**

[image]

**Image 2**

[image]

Comment: You can't commit an empty directory.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: to commit a new, empty-ish folder, you'll have to put a file in it. (.keep, .gitignore, or README are common choices)

Git "detects no changes" because git uses its `index` file to generate commits, and `index` only tracks files. Directories exist in the `index` only as parts of file paths.

Here's some discussion of [why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26079618/why-cant-i-commit-an-empty-folder-in-git) this is the case, and a link to the git [FAQ](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#Can_I_add_empty_directories.3F) on the subject. On the off chance you actually need to commit an 'empty' folder, here are some [hacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541253/commit-empty-folder-structure-with-git) that will make it work.