# I dont have a .gitignore file but dirs and files are being ignored

Tags: git, gitignore

I've searched my box. I have no global or local .gitignore file. the dir's and files are not in in .git/info/excludes

but if I `git status --ignored` my dir's are listed there. Even if I change the dir names they are still in the list of ignored items.

Any ideas would be handy

### edit

```
# On branch master
# Initial commit.
#
# Ignored files:
#   (use "git add -f <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       dir1/
#       dir2/
nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)
```

yes there are files and folders in dir 1 and 2

I tried `git check-ignore dir1` No output was returned

Comment: Can you provide output of the `git status --ignored` command?

Comment: Try `git check-ignore <dir>` to see why `dir` is ignored.

Comment: Are there files in the directories? Git won't care about (empty) directories. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030230/does-git-ignore-empty-folders).

Comment: see question edit

Comment: What files are inside `dir1/` and `dir2/`? Try running `check-ignore` on them.

Comment: You need to `git add` the files you want to commit, it even says so on the message you posted...

Comment: Well thank you @m0skit0 but I have already done that. confused as I am that it is ignoring said files I do understand how to use git.

Comment: most are .txt config files @NilsWerner

Comment: also no output on them from the git check

Comment: Point `check-ignore` at a _file_ inside one of those directories, not the directory itself. I would also add `-v` for good measure: `git check-ignore -v dir1/file1`. I wonder if you've got them ignored in `.git/info/exclude`?

Comment: It's also possible that those directories include their own `.git/` directory (that is, you've got a Git repository inside a Git repository). By design, Git doesn't track nested repositories. You'll have to use submodules, subtrees, or something similar if you want to nest repositories. Try `ls -A dir1/` to see if it contains a `.git/` directory.

Comment: Hi Chris, yea the .git in the folders were my first thought. I did a check to confirm again anyway and no ```.git``` are anywhere besides the main repo.
I checked the ```.git/info/excludes``` first as that's what I assumed the issue was, but it was untouched. I have also tried looking at the ```git check-ignore -v dir1/file1``` no output. I've also looked for a global ignore file or a profile related one and cant find anything. I may have to delete the repo and try again.

Comment: @H30, is anything funny happening at the filesystem level, e.g. `dir1`/ and `dir2/` might live on different partitions but be mounted to these locations?

Comment: No they are all on the same area. all created there and no separate partitions for this drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I still have no idea what was wrong or what the issue was but I did a `git clean` and it seems to have sorted the issue. Thank you all for your suggestions and input.