# Sublime sidebar folders/files not refreshing on git checkout?

Tags: git, sublimetext3

When I create/delete a folder or file in one of my branches, and then checkout another branch, the updates aren't reflected in my folders, however they are reflected on my site. I'm using sftp for sublime and for some reason I can't seem to get the sidebar to update new file changes when I checkout other branches. Anyone have any ideas to get this working?

Comment: Are those folders empty? If yes see [Does git ignore empty folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030230/does-git-ignore-empty-folders)

Comment: @caramba well lets say it's a file (it is) the file shouldn't show up in my other branch in sublime, but it does.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: you must `git add` the file and then `git commit` the updated index.

(This is based on comments above.)

If you created a file in the work-tree, but have not `git add`-ed the file, that's an *untracked file*.  The precise definition of *untracked file* is *a file that is not in the index*.  The index is also called the *staging area* since it's where you update (i.e., stage) the files for the *next* commit you will make.  The `git add` step copies the file into the index, ready for the next `git commit` to commit it.  You have to finish this process with the `git commit` (well, you have to finish it eventually—you can wait, if you like, and copy more files into the index, or even overwrite the one you just copied in).

Git leaves untracked files alone, at least as much as it can.  As long as the file is untracked (is not in the index) you can switch branches all you like and the file just sits there.

Once you add and commit the file, it becomes an ordinary file in that commit, just like every other file in that commit.  The `git commit` step simply packages up every file that is in the index, in the form it has in the index right when you run `git commit`, and makes that into a new, read-only (completely),<sup>1</sup> permanent (mostly),<sup>2</sup> commit.

Note that when you change an existing work-tree file, the *older* version is still in the index (if it's in there at at all, i.e., if the file is tracked).  You still have to `git add modified-file` to copy the updated version into the index.  That's why Git is constantly forcing you to `git add` everything: you must first copy it into the index, even if there's already an older version *in* the index.

Checking out any existing commit fills the index and work-tree with the files from that commit.  Checking out some *other* commit will remove, from the index and work-tree, any files that were in your previous checked-out commit but are not in your new checked-out commit.  (Note that [in some cases, you can carry un-committed changes around in your index and work-tree while switching branches, but sometimes you can't do this.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22053757/1256452)  The details are kind of messy.)

Hence, after running `git add new-file` and `git commit` while on branch `feature-A`, doing `git checkout feature-B` will switch you from the new commit, which has the file (it's in the index → tracked, and in the work-tree → visible) to your existing older commit on `feature-B`.  The older commit *doesn't* have the new file, so it comes *out* of the index and Git *removes* it from your work-tree.

Note that now that the tip commit of `feature-A` *has* the file.  If you are still on `feature-B` and you *create* the file and leave it untracked, it's just an untracked file.  It's not in the index.  You now *can't* `git checkout feature-A` because Git will have to *overwrite* your untracked file.  You must remove it (so that it's not in the way) or add-and-commit it (so that it's tracked and clean) so that Git can blow away *that* copy and replace it with the copy from `feature-A`.

(Exercise: when you do check out the commit from `feature-A`, will the file that was new back then, be in the index?)

---

<sup>1</sup>Every object stored inside a Git repository is always completely read-only.  There are four object types: *commit*, *tree*, *blob*, and *annotated tag*.  The two you will see most directly are commit and blob: commit objects hold your commits, and blob objects hold your file data.

<sup>2</sup>Commits stick around as long as you can *find* them.  A branch name like `master` identifies one particular commit, and that commit finds its parent.  The parent commit finds its own parent, which finds yet another parent, and so on.  In general, in Git, you will add new commits without ever forgetting / abandoning the old ones, by the simple method of having the *new* commit remember, as its parent, whichever commit was the latest on some branch before then.  The branch name will then just identify the newest commit.

Every once in a while you find that some commit was terrible and should be forgotten.  As long as you haven't given that commit to someone else, you can simply adjust your branch names and other existing commits to *forget* or *abandon* the one you don't like.  Forgotten / abandoned commit IDs get saved in a side log called a *reflog*, for a while.  Eventually the reflog entries expire, and only then will Git really reclaim the commit.  The reflog entries live for at least 30 days by default, so you have up to a month to change your mind and get a commit back, after abandoning it.

This all means that commits are *mostly* permanent.  They are not 100% guaranteed permanent, but they won't be lost by accident.  Since they're also read-only, this means that your historical files, which are saved in these commits, are available to you forever.

Comment: So if I git add . , git commit -m "something", and then git push to my branch. Then go to a different branch they should be updated?

Comment: That doesn't work, at least the way that I just explained it, my files still don't update.

Comment: That depends on your current directory (what directory does `.` represent?). Check with `git status` as well: new files should show status `A` (new file added) before committing. Existing modified files should show status `M` (modified). By default, `git status` shows you two sections: changes staged for commit (this is what's in your index as compared to what's in the current commit), and changes not staged for commit (what's in your work-tree. as compared to what's in your index).

Comment: `git push` is for transferring *commits* (not files, except to the extent that the commits *contain* files) from one Git to another Git. If you're looking at another Git when making changes in your Git, *then* you will need to `git push` items. If you're looking at your own repository at all times, you don't need to `git push`.

Comment: (I have no idea what sublime sftp does; this is all just on the *Git* side of things.)