# do git init in a folder but git failed to add some subfolders

Tags: git

while i'm using git to init the root folder which i've created by use hugo newsite hugo-g, i find not all the subfolders in the root folder are been added to the git.

below are the file permission details:

```
╰─ ll -al
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  12 robot  staff   384B Jul 20 22:50 .
drwxr-xr-x  51 robot  staff   1.6K Jul 18 16:22 ..
drwxr-xr-x   9 robot  staff   288B Jul 20 22:50 .git
drwxr-xr-x   3 robot  staff    96B Jul 10 17:56 archetypes
-rw-r--r--   1 robot  staff   7.8K Jul 20 20:23 config.toml
drwxr-xr-x   4 robot  staff   128B Jul 20 21:11 content
drwxr-xr-x   2 robot  staff    64B Jul 10 17:56 data
drwxr-xr-x   2 robot  staff    64B Jul 10 17:56 layouts
drwxr-xr-x  13 robot  staff   416B Jul 20 22:01 public
drwxr-xr-x   3 robot  staff    96B Jul 19 11:13 resources
drwxr-xr-x   2 robot  staff    64B Jul 10 17:56 static
drwxr-xr-x   7 robot  staff   224B Jul 20 22:33 themes
```

below are the result after i've done the action: git init

```
╰─ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/robot/code/interests/hugo-g/.git/
╰─ ls
archetypes  config.toml content     data        layouts     public      resources   static      themes
╰─ git status
On branch master

No commits yet

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    archetypes/
    config.toml
    public/
    themes/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)


#I tried with commands provided by @Sepideha and @melpomene, but it still not works, and the result is like this.

git add .
git status
    new file:   archetypes/default.md
    new file:   config.toml
    new file:   public/404.html
    new file:   public/archives/index.html
    new file:   public/archives/index.xml
    new file:   public/categories/index.html
    new file:   public/categories/index.xml
    new file:   public/css/style-twzjdbqhmnnacqs0pwwdzcdbt8yhv8giawvjqjmyfoqnvazl0dalmnhdkvp7.min.css
    new file:   public/images/cover-v1.2.0.jpg
    new file:   public/images/cover.jpg
    new file:   public/index.html
    new file:   public/index.xml
    new file:   public/js/script-pcw6v3xilnxydl1vddzazdverrnn9ctynvnxgwho987mfyqkuylcb1nlt.min.js
    new file:   public/page/1/index.html
    new file:   public/sitemap.xml
    new file:   public/tags/index.html
    new file:   public/tags/index.xml
    new file:   themes


git add * 
git status

    new file:   archetypes/default.md
    new file:   config.toml
    new file:   public/404.html
    new file:   public/archives/index.html
    new file:   public/archives/index.xml
    new file:   public/categories/index.html
    new file:   public/categories/index.xml
    new file:   public/css/style-twzjdbqhmnnacqs0pwwdzcdbt8yhv8giawvjqjmyfoqnvazl0dalmnhdkvp7.min.css
    new file:   public/images/cover-v1.2.0.jpg
    new file:   public/images/cover.jpg
    new file:   public/index.html
    new file:   public/index.xml
    new file:   public/js/script-pcw6v3xilnxydl1vddzazdverrnn9ctynvnxgwho987mfyqkuylcb1nlt.min.js
    new file:   public/page/1/index.html
    new file:   public/sitemap.xml
    new file:   public/tags/index.html
    new file:   public/tags/index.xml
    new file:   themes

the subfolder like data, content,layouts, resources... still miss.


tree -L 2
╰─ tree -L 2
.
├── archetypes
│   └── default.md
├── config.toml
├── content
│   ├── page
│   └── post
├── data
├── layouts
├── public
│   ├── 404.html
│   ├── archives
│   ├── categories
│   ├── css
│   ├── images
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── index.xml
│   ├── js
│   ├── page
│   ├── sitemap.xml
│   └── tags
├── resources
│   └── _gen
├── static
└── themes
    ├── AllinOne
    ├── BeyondNothing
    ├── Binario
```

OS:Darwin robot.local 18.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 18.6.0: Thu Apr 25 23:16:27 PDT 2019; root:xnu-4903.261.4~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
git-version: version 2.20.0
hugo-version: Hugo Static Site Generator v0.55.6/extended darwin/amd64 BuildDate: unknown
go-version: go version go1.12.5 darwin/amd64

I hope all the subfolder in root folder could be added to the git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with the help of my college huafeng, i finally figured out the reason. As a reason, git won't trace the folder with no file in it.
And i also find following answers:
[Does git ignore empty folders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030230/does-git-ignore-empty-folders)
there says, Git is a content tracker. Empty directories are not content.

Answer (score 4):

`git init` doesn't add any files. It just creates an (initially empty) repository.

If you want to add all files and subdirectories in the directory to the repository, you need to

```
git add .
git commit
```

(The latter command will open a text editor so you can type your first commit message.)

Comment: @albertjone Your edit shows it worked just fine. Your question doesn't mention that some of those subdirectories are empty.

Answer (score 1):

In your root  directory you need to do the following 3 steps to add the files to git repository:

```
    git add *
    git commit -m "added file to the repo"
    git push
```

Comment: Any difference between missing directories & ok ones? Are they nested repository? Do they contain .git file by themselves?

Comment: Probably the missing directories have files that are filtered in .gitignore file? Try to check .gitignore file.