# This path skips through empty directories even though directory is not empty

Tags: git, github

I have two directories in my repo

1. src
2. tests

now, tests is actually a new directory(which is not empty). It does have a tests.csproj and related files into it.

Now, on my local everything looks good but when I push it to GitHub, couple of unexpected things start happening:

the tests folder shows up as

1. `Tests/projectFolder` on github. Which has multiple things which are wrong. I was expecting to see just `tests` folder. I have no idea why it shows full path to the project folder.
2. Suddenly the `tests` folder is capitalized without a reason, now sure why.
3. When I hover over the folder it shows `This path skips through empty directories`
   message on github. Which could be a problem if it in fact was en empty folder but it really is not.
4. when I include a .gitkeep file in the tests folder as suggested on this link: [Does git ignore empty folders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030230/does-git-ignore-empty-folders) then it sholves the problem that it shows the entire path of `Tests/projectFolder` instead of tests but as you can notice the capitalization issue is still there. And also the I just do not want to put a .gitkeep file in any of my folder if I do not have to. Which I think is a fair expectation if my folder is not empty.

I have multiple problems with it. First of all, I may have to go through this exercise(of adding (.gitkeep) file only if it was an empty folder. If it is not an empty folder then I should just be able to add a new folder and add new files in it and it should just show up on GitHub as it is. Also, I have no idea where is this involuntary capitalization is coming from. Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you rename the local one to be `Tests`? Just curious if "changes" will be detected by git.

Comment: I actually renamed the folder to tests-2 and then back to tests which resolved the issue. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Great. Glad we were able to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question: The *skipping through empty directories* thing is just some eye-candy on the GitHub website. They want to take off the load of skipping through a deep tree of directories off you, if each directory has only one child directory. Instead, they show a quick link into the next directory which has more than a single child directory. However, in your Git repository, the directories are stored as you'd expect.

But, I can't figure out, where the capitilization comes from. Git should track your files and directories just as you named them—which includes the correct case. Did you double-check the directory's name on your local disk?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. For the capitalization part, it actually helped when I renamed  tests to tests-2 and then back to tests. I am still not sure what caused the capitalization issue but at least it is resolved now.