# GitHub won't upload folders to repository

Tags: github

I am new to GitHub and I am trying to drag and drop my folders into my repository. But when I drop my folders, nothing happens.

Do you know what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Fast explanation is: git simply ignores empty folders/directories.
By the way this is not a GitHub specific thing. For further information (and the technically correct explanation) I recommend this post:
[Does git ignore empty folders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030230/does-git-ignore-empty-folders)