# Gitignore ignores folder instead of file

Tags: git, gitignore

I'm trying to do something very simple: I have in `src/main/resources/` a file called application.properties that i want to not push to git.

Inside the `resources` folder I have other folders that I need to push.

**.gitignore**

```
...
*application.properties
...
```

But when I try to add files to git then it ignores the `resources` folder (and obviously also the files inside). Even if I change the `.gitignore` file to `src/main/resources/application.properties` gives the same problem.

How can I ignore just the application.properties file and not the folder where it is?

Comment: Git only tracks files, not directories. If there are no non-ignored files in a directory it doesn’t exist to Git.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here: [Does git ignore empty folders?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3030246/10648655)

Basically you'd need to add a empty `.gitkeep` file inside your folder, in the original post is also a comment with a script to do that automatically.

Then just add

```
src/main/resources/application.properties
```

to your .gitignore and the folder resources should still be there.

Answer (score 0):

- In the root folder of the git repository, having a `.gitignore` with the below line is enough to ignore the file:

`src/main/resources/application.properties`

If you have a different behavior is due to another rule and you should investigate.

- You could have multiple `.gitignore` files in a git repository, so the other possibility is to add a `.gitignore` file inside the `src/main/resources/` folder with the line:

`application.properties`