# How can I add a directory tree to my github repo?

Tags: github

I've been working on a project that's fairly far a long now and I decided it's time to use some sort of version control etc.  I decided to go with github.  Before I get in too deep let me state explicitly that I am new to github.

My project resides in a directory that contains myriad subdirectories and files of all different kinds.  I'd like to take my project directory as is (structure and all) and put it in my github repo.

I followed the tutorials on github's webpage, created the repo, and manually added some files.  Obviously I don't want to manually add every file (there are several hundred).  I'd like to know how I can add the root directory or for that matter any parent directory and all files/folders in said said directory.  In other words I'm looking for a recursive add.

I read on this SO page ([How to create folder in github repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12258399/how-to-create-folder-in-github-repository)) that you can just use

```
git add directory/
```

That works fine for me when I'm dealing with the lowest level directory, but when I try the same command on a directory with subdirectories my terminal just sits there and I have to ctrl-c.  I can't tell if it's just taking a long time (as I mentioned there are lots of files) or if this is just the wrong way to add a directory with subdirectories.

Apologies in advance if this is a super ignorant question -- I have looked at a lot of blogs/posts/etc and I cannot find a solution that seems to work.

Comment: Turns out that it just takes a while -- patients is a virtue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use the Current Working Directory

Assuming you're on Linux or OS X, from the command line you would do the following:

```
git add .
```

from the root of your repository tree. That will add all non-ignored files, including non-empty directories, into the repository.

Comment: Thanks!  I actually saw that elsewhere and tried that and ctrl-c'ed it because it was seemingly stalled.  I let it run for a while (several minutes) and it completed.  Checked with status -s and it appears to be fine.  I guess it just takes a while to compute the hashes for everything when there are a ton of files?

Comment: @Doov It certainly can, because git-add has to modify the index for every file in the tree. If you have an extremely large tree, and especially if you have a lot of large binary blobs, it may take more time than you expect.

Comment: Ah, makes sense.  I do indeed have extremely large binary blobs.  Thanks for the answer/explanation!

Answer (score 0):

From the root directory (the one with all the subdirectories), use `git add -A`.

If you have a ton of subdirectories and files, it may take a long while, so just let it sit there until it's done.

Comment: Don't rely on `-A` without a pathspec. See git-add(1) for deprecation and explanation.