# How do I create folders on GItHub?

Tags: python, github, directory

hiii, i have a repository in github but i still learning how to use it. my question is, i got some files there named as adivinhacao.py, forca.py and jogos.py and i want to put them in a folder to organize my profile but i already uploaded them. i really want to learn it so i would be very thankful if someone could help me. :)))[image: screenshot of my github]

i expect to understand how i create folders in githb

Comment: you create folders on your local machine and add the files there. Then add the files to git, commit and push the changes to the remote repository

Comment: look here: [How do I create a folder in a GitHub repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12258399/how-do-i-create-a-folder-in-a-github-repository)