# Commit empty folder structure (with git)

Tags: git, gitignore

I have data directory in project's root. It has images directory and some files. Here is example:

```
data
├── images
│   ├── image1.jpg
│   ├── image2.jpg
│   └── image3.jpg 
├── results.csv
└── r.txt
```

What to write in gitignore, to ignore files from data/ directory (that is results.csv and r.txt) and files from images/ directory (image.jpg, image2.jpg, image3.jpg)?

When I commit it, folder structure in repository should be:

```
data/
└── images/
```

So, I just want empty folder structure to be commited.

Comment: See: [How do I add an empty directory to a git repository](http://stackoverflow.com/q/115983/1402846).

Answer (score 107, accepted):

In Git, you cannot commit empty folders, because Git does not actually save folders, only files. You'll have to create some placeholder file inside those directories if you actually want them to be "empty" (i.e. you have no committable content).

Comment: Other solution for that is add a README file into empty directory. The solution is explain [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229885/what-are-the-differences-between-gitignore-and-gitkeep)

Comment: If you missed Pang's comment on the OP above, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-can-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository

Answer (score 145):

Just add a file `.gitkeep` in every folder you want committed.

On windows do so by right clicking when in the folder and select: Git bash from here. Then type: `touch .gitkeep`

Comment: What about `.keep` instead? It is agnostic to git.

Comment: Yes, it actually doesn't matter that much how you'll call the file

Comment: The `git` prefix, though, gives a hint of why there's an otherwise pointless empty file lying around.

Comment: The git prefix is intended for git-generated files. Just landed here from this other thread discussing this exact issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-can-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository

Comment: The `.git` prefix is assumed to mean git will process it in a special way, so it is confusing. It would be better to use `.keep` and place text inside the file written in plain English explaining the purpose of the file. Even though `.keep` is not immediately obvious what it means, that is fine as we are programmers after all, and it is easy to learn what it means by looking inside the file. Once you understand what it means it is a memorable name. Go for names that are short and memorable. After a time, the brevity of it allows your mind to process it more quickly than `.keep_dir_in_git`.

Comment: I found it useful and time saving to put a dummy file in each directory. I say each directory, just incase the dir is not empty now, but may be in future. Use: `find . -type d -exec touch {}/.gitkeep \;`

Comment: This won't work if your website expects the folder to be empty.

Comment: thanks for the tip

Comment: in my case the folder has files, but still after doing `git add --all` not working

Answer (score 60):

This is easy.

tell `.gitignore` to ignore everything except `.gitignore` and the folders you want to keep. Put `.gitignore` into folders that you want to keep in the repo.

Contents of the top-most `.gitignore`:

```
# ignore everything except .gitignore and folders that I care about:
*
!images*
!.gitignore
```

In the nested `images` folder this is your `.gitignore`:

```
# ignore everything except .gitignore
*
!.gitignore
```

Note, you must spell out in the .gitignore the names of the folders you don't want to be ignored in the folder where that .gitignore is located. Otherwise they are, obviously, ignored.

Your folders in the repo will, obviously, NOT be empty, as each one will have `.gitignore` in it, but that part can be ignored, right. :)

Comment: actually, this is the solution to the question, as it spares you with the hassle to deal with new files inside the folder in question. empty folders are often used for temporarily created files, which might cause problems you're dealing with git commands on other systems on which the repo gets checked out.

Comment: Im  confused, why would you ignore everything apart from gitignore? Im trying to understand, but it doesnt make sense. I ended up going with `find . -type d -exec touch {}/.gitkeep \;` but it would be nice to understand this alternative, as it seems a popular upvoted one.

Comment: @redfox05 the OP needs at least one file in those directories so that git will include the empty folder structure. If we do not un-ignore the .gitignore file, the folder will be empty and git will not include it.

Answer (score 44):

Recursively create .gitkeep files

```
find . -type d -empty -not -path "./.git/*" -exec touch {}/.gitkeep \;
```

Comment: This should be the chosen answer.

Comment: I'm stuck using a Windows machine for work. Does anyone know how to do this in powershell?

Comment: @philiporlando Use git bash on windows.

Answer (score 7):

Traditionally whenever I've wanted to commit and empty directory structure, I create the structure and then in the leaf directories place an empty file called `empty.txt`.

Then when I put stuff in that's ready to commit, I can simply remove the `empty.txt` file and commit the real files.

i.e.

- data/

  - images/

    - empty.txt

Comment: what he also needed is for the contents of the folders to be ignored by git. Every folder needs a `.gitignore` in it. It effectively replaces `empty.txt`

Comment: Or perhaps `.empty`.

Answer (score 4):

Consider also just doing `mkdir -p data/images` in your Makefile, if the directory needs to be there during build.

If that's not good enough, just create an empty file in data/images and ignore data.

```
touch data/images/.gitignore
git add data/images/.gitignore
git commit -m "Add empty .gitignore to keep data/images around"
echo data >> .gitignore
git add .gitignore
git commit -m "Add data to .gitignore"
```

Comment: I was getting the error on Jenkins because I had unit test for empty location and it works perfectly fine ! Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can make an empty commit with `git commit --allow-empty`, but that will not allow you to commit an empty folder structure as git does not know or care about folders as objects themselves -- just the files they contain.

Answer (score 1):

According to their FAQ, GIT doesn't track empty directories.

[Git FAQ](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#Can_I_add_empty_directories.3F)

However, there are workarounds based on your needs and your project requirements.

Basically if you want to track an empty directory you can place a `.gitkeep` file in there. The file can be blank and it will just work. This is Gits way of tracking an empty directory.

Another option is to provide documentation for the directory. You can just add a readme file in it describing its expected usage. Git will track the folder because it has a file in it and you have now provided documentation to you and/or whoever else might be using the source code.

If you are building a web app you may find it useful to just add an index.html file which may contain a permission denied message if the folder is only accessible through the app. Codeigniter does this with all their directories.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add file named as .keep in images folder.you can now stage and commit and also able to add folder to version control.

Create a empty file in images folder
`$ touch .keep`

`$ git status`

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

Untracked files:
  (use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)

    images/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

`$ git add .`

`$ git commit -m "adding empty folder"`