# Can I handcraft my own commit for an empty directory?

Tags: git, git-commit

The answer to "[How can I add an empty directory to a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-can-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository)" is you can't through regular git commands, because the staging only has files, not folders.

Commits, on the other hand, do have folders, so a commit could conceivably have an empty folder.

How would create a commit with an empty folder? What about a commit to remove an empty folder? Can I add the empty folder on top of other changes (made via the staging area)?

Note: Here is evidence that commits can contain folders:

```
$ git cat-file -p 6c07af3
tree 3d6e2028b57fba5cd2c5f1f01cdd5be9814335ec
author *** 1452398070 -0500
committer *** 1452398070 -0500

A commit

$ git cat-file -p 3d6e20
100644 blob e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391    file1
040000 tree e4af7700f8c091d18cc15f39c184490125fb0d17    folder
```

Note that it stores which things are files and which are folders, as well as file and folder names. What I would want to do is create my own git commit object, without going through the staging process.

Comment: Be aware: The asker is downvote any attempt to answer

Comment: That question contains an answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8944077/1256452 that is as close as you can get: you can use the semi-secret empty tree as an entry in a regular tree.  Note all the caveats in the answer, though; the short version is "don't do it".

Comment: @codeWizard Although I am glad at the interest in this question, all the answers so far are wrong, and the voting reflects this.

Comment: You don't have to accept answer, but to appreciate people who are trying to help you.

Comment: @codeWizard Again, I appreciate you taking interest. The downvote does not mean I do not like you or anything, simply that I disagree with the answer. If you think it is correct, convince me so.

Comment: It cant be done. period. git does not trace folders like svn it track content.
http://steindom.com/articles/add-empty-directory-git-repository 
I will be glad to lean how you can do it, but you cant

Comment: @codeWizard Using internal commands, it is revealed that it does, for example, track folders and files separately. Unless I have made some error in my Note. Also see torek's comment.

Answer (score -1):

In Git, you cannot commit empty folders, because Git does not actually save folders, only files. You'll have to create some placeholder file inside those directories if you actually want them to be "empty" (i.e. you have no committable content).
for more info and your answer [Commit empty folder structure (with git)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541253/commit-empty-folder-structure-with-git)

Comment: The staging area does not track folders. Commits do (I checked).

Comment: Downcast the question so it will be removed. he is downvote all answers. we shell return him the same so his Q will be deleted

Comment: @stackprogramer raise the flag if you wish the Q to be deleted

Comment: unfortunately i has not enough reputation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100267/discussion-between-codewizard-and-stackprogramer).

Comment: Maybe you could use toraks comment up above to make a new answer.

Answer (score -2):

> The answer to "How can I add an empty directory to a Git repository?" is you can't through regular git commands, because the staging only has files, not folders.

You can do it if you will add empty file usually named `.gitkeep` to your folder so git will track this folder since it has content.

```
# go to the desired folder    
cd <folder>

# Create empty file 
touch .gitkeep

# git status will now show the file so you can add the folder to git
```

---

Git does not track files !!! it track content regardless of its location, so empty folder does not have any content to track. in order to track them they must have content.

`.gitkeep` is just a placeholder.
A dummy file, so git will not forget about the directory, since git tracks only files and not directories.

---

As you can see here git does not care what is the name of the file or where its located. It store the metadata in a different location then the file.

[image]

Comment: Although you can add a `.gitkeep` file to an empty folder, when you commit it, you will be committing a folder with exactly one file, not an empty folder.

Comment: Exactly, since git CANNOT track empty folders. there is no way to add empty folder otherwise.

Comment: You are just copying answers from the linked question.

Comment: My edit addresses why this answer and its premise is incorrect.