# why does git can't track new directory?

Tags: git

I was create new directory found git can't track.

[image]

then create test directory

[image]

git not track directory ?

check ignore config:

[image]

add new file `git` could work

[image]

this is bug something ?
git version: 2.13.3

Thank you very much

Comment: git doesn't track empty directories...

Comment: Git tracks the content. The content is stored in files. Git doesn't track empty directories by design.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will not see an empty directory in git, as git saves only files and not folders. In order to add the folder you will need to create a file inside.

Please see [Commit empty folder structure (with git)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541253/commit-empty-folder-structure-with-git)