# files not showing in git client sourcetree

Tags: git

I'm using git client sourcetree to manage git repository,In eclipse project explorer, files and folders with question mark sign [?] showing in image mentioned below are being show in sourcetree in unstaged files area but files without question mark sign not showing in sourcetree and also files adding to java project is not showing in sourcetree......any help appreciated thanks.

[image]

[image]

Above images for sourcetree showing only files which have [?]mark in project explorer visible in sourcetree,why the folder src/main/java and src/test/java not visible in sourcetree?

Comment: These directories are empty and you cannot commit empty directories with git : https://stackoverflow.com/a/14541263/369946

Comment: thanks for respond @Benjamin, if I put something in these empty directories this still doesn't solve the problem

Comment: @Benjamin you were right I was making silly mistake ,my problem get solved...thanks