# gitignore contents of subdirectories

Tags: git, gitignore

I've have directory structure like :

```
a
|-- b
|   |-- qfq.txt
|   |-- ewfw.txt
|   | ...
|
|-- c
|   |-- wgfw.txt
|   |-- wjkh.txt
|   | ...
| ...
```

I need to gitignore all txt files in `a/*/` . I  tried `/a/*/*.txt` and `/a/**/*.txt`, but they don't work.

Please help. Thank you.

---

Updated :
Solved

`/a/**/*.txt` works. Also, I came to know that [git doesn't commit empty folders](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14541263/10314925), not knowing which I thought the commands not working properly.

Thanks @JonathonReinhar, @phd,  pankaj for quick response.

Comment: Why not use additional `.gitignore` files in those directories? It's much simpler.

Comment: In what way they don't work? Were the files already committed?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Yes. This will be simpler. The reason I'm avoiding this is because the above structure is quite redundant in my project structure and I was thinking of a central control on gitignore.

Comment: @phd The files were not committed. On including /a/*/*.txt or /a/**/*.txt in .gitignore, it stops tracking txts at /a/* which is right. But, suppose when I push this structure to remote repo, it should push /a/* without containing txt files, which is not happening here. If a directory is empty after ignoring txts, it doesn't push directories to remote repo.

Comment: `git` doesn't track empty directories. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/115983/7976758

Comment: @phd yes. got it. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding this in your .gitignore should do -

```
$ cat .gitignore 
a/**/*.txt
```

Check this, I created the same directory and files structure

```
$ find . -name *.txt 
./a/c/wjkh.txt
./a/c/wgfw.txt
./a/b/qfq.txt
./a/b/ewfw.txt
```

but my "git status" is clean

```
$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

**Make sure you first commit the .gitignore to the repo then only it will start ignoring files.**

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks buddy. I got it.