# grunt-init: How can I copy or create an empty directory?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I want copy an empty directory from my root folder into the new initialized project. I want do this, to provide an initial directory structure for new projects.

I have such empty directories in the folder 'my-template/root/' but that will not be copied by:

```
    // Files to copy (and process).
    var files = init.filesToCopy(props);

    // Actually copy (and process) files.
    init.copyAndProcess(files, props);
```

I tried this:

```
    // to copy also the empty directories
    init.copy('myDir1/');
    init.copy('myDir2/');
```

But than grunt-init crashes with:

```
Error: Unable to read "grunt-init-example/root/myDir1/" file (Error code: EISDIR).
```

What have I to do, to get an empty directory to the destination folder?

I use grunt@0.4.0 and grunt-init@0.2.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inspired by the answer of Nick Mitchinson, I use this workaround:

```
// module dependencies
var join = require("path").join;
// empty directories will not be copied, so we need to create them manual
grunt.file.mkdir( join(init.destpath(), 'myDir1') );
grunt.file.mkdir( join(init.destpath(), 'myDir2') );
```

**Update:**

Alternative solution is to add `.gitkeep` files to the empty directories. Than the directories are no more empty and will be listed with filesToCopy().

For more details about `.gitkeep` look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7229996/496587

Answer (score 2):

Try taking a look this [this article](http://iambot.net/building-a-javascript-project-using-node-dot-js-and-grunt.html)

The part relevant to creating a directory is:

```
var root = path.normalize(__dirname+"/relative/path/you/want");
grunt.file.mkdir(root);
```

however, reading the whole this would probably be good.

Comment: Your given link is dead :(

Answer (score 0):

I create an empty **__empty_file.txt** file inside the empty folders which I want to get copied.
Inside my template.js file I do the following:

1. Store files which matches with our (**__empty_file.txt**) by iterating over files object returned by ***init.filesToCopy(props)*** to an array.
2. Create directories using **grunt.file.mkdir** for each item in the above array and remove this file from files reference which was returned by **init.filesToCopy**. This has to be called before the call to **init.copyAndProcess**.