# Jgit traverse content of a commit from specific branch

Tags: java, git, jgit

How can I traverse with jgit all content  of an specific commit from an specific branch?

```
ObjectId commitId = repository.resolve(currentCommit.getCommitHash());
RevWalk revWalk = new RevWalk(repository);
RevCommit commit = revWalk.parseCommit(commitId);
RevTree tree = commit.getTree();
TreeWalk treeWalk = new TreeWalk(repository);
treeWalk.addTree(tree);
treeWalk.setRecursive(true);
treeWalk.setFilter(PathFilter.create(currentPath));
if (!treeWalk.next()) {
    throw new IllegalStateException(
            "Did not find expected file README.md");
}
```

This code retrieve me a special file from the commit but I want traverse all content of an commit.

Answer (score 2):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19950970/305973), it lists files and folders. You can use `setRecursive(true)` and leave off the `isSubtree` branch when you are just interested in file paths.