# gitignore shouldn't track files in subdirectory, but should track the directory structure

Tags: git, gitignore

I have these files:

```
Static/Images/img1.png
Static/Images/img2.jpg
Static/Files/file1.pdf
Static/Files/file2.docx
```

And I want to store the directory structure, meaning:

```
Static
Static/Images
Static/Files
```

But I don't wanna store these files, because they are just a repository of  unnecessary static files.
On the other hand, storing the directory structure is important for me.

I tried many things, searched a lot, but I wasn't successful.
Gitignore is harder than seem.

Some tries:

1.

```
Static/Images/*
Static/Files/*
```

2.

```
Static/Images/**
Static/Files/**
```

3.

```
Static/*
!Static/Images/
!Static/Files/
```

Comment: Git doesn't like storing empty directories, so unless you have *something* in there, you're going to have issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can’t do that; Git doesn’t track directories at all, and creates them based on the files they contain. The usual solution is to add and track an empty `.gitkeep` file to each directory. So:

```
Static/Images/*
!.gitkeep
```

Comment: Relevant question with discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229885

Comment: You helped a lot, thank you! It's exactly what I need.

Comment: I tried this, but it isn't working. Can you figure something out?

Comment: @osmanpontes: In what way isn’t it working?

Comment: It was a dummie stuff. I have a folder `MyProject/` that have everything inside it. I tried `Static/Images` so it didn't work. It was just change to `MyProject/Static/Images`.