# How do I copy folders on GitHub?

Tags: github, directory

Whenever I try to add folders to git hub it gives "files are empty" am i missing something? Anyone know why? It seems to me that I'm adding the folders wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Git/GitHub doesn't store empty directories.

Convention is to put empty `.gitkeep` file in it.

---

Do you need more detailed technical explanation? [Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7229996/1348344)

Comment: But the folders are not empty

Comment: Could you link me the repo?

Answer (score 0):

`find . -type d -empty -not -path '*/\.*' -exec touch {}/.gitkeep \;` will ignore empty directories inside the .git folder