# Add a nested folder to git

Tags: git

So I have a git project `myproj` cloned into my system. When I add individually changed files for commit using `git add .` it works fine. Now I have added a new folder `new-folder` inside the project as `myproj/app/scripts/new-folder` and want the `new-folder` to add to my repository but `git add .` or `git add --all app/scripts/new-folder` or `git add --all` do not work.

Comment: You can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-can-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository/20388370#20388370 article

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you try to add an empty folder to your repository and this is currently not supported by git (check the git [FAQ](http://%20Check%20here:%20https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#Can_I_add_empty_directories.3F)).

If this is the case then you find already some answers to your question on SO.
For example see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-can-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository). If you need an "empty" folder there are some "tricks" or "conventions", again see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-can-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229885/what-are-the-differences-between-gitignore-and-gitkeep).

If your folder is not empty, then a simple `git add new-folder` should do the trick. This will also **add all** files within the folder.

If you do not see the non-empty folder as the result of `git status`, you could also check if the folder name is not contained in your `.gitignore`.

Comment: Thats why you use .gitkeep files.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your new folder has something and run below git command

`git add *` --> it will add all modifyed files and folders

**Ex:** you need to add new-folder to git you need go myproj then run **git add *** in Then it will simply include all folders and file in this path --> myproj/app/scripts/new-folder

> But your **new-folder** should have some files