# git clone does not download all files

Tags: git, clone

When I fire the below command:

```
git clone <url>
```

I can just see 1 folder and in that folder just 1 file  viz .gitkeep.

Why my other folders and files arent getting downloaded?

Comment: Most likely those other files are not committed.

Comment: In order to answer this, we will need some more information. What files are missing? Is there a gitignore? Are there any errors or warnings when you run `git clone`? Are any of the missing folders empty?

Comment: Is it by any chance a public repo so we can take a look? And post the command output of `git clone <url>`

Comment: @LLSv2.0  no, there is no gitignore. No errors are encountered when git clone is run. Does having empty folder prevent downloading of other folders?

Comment: @Teharez its not a public repo. Yes will surely post the output of git clone

Comment: @SushantGokhale An empty folder will not prevent the download of other folders, but I do believe that an empty folder will be ignored itself.

Comment: @LLSv2.0 Yes git ignores empty folders. That's the reason the file .gitkeep is there. It is not intepreted in any special way by git like .gitignore, but solely there so the folder will be created when cloning/pulling. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7229996/6900162).

Comment: What branch your other folders on?

Answer (score 8):

Since, you have mentioned that there isn't `.gitignore` file, There is a chance that the files that aren't getting downloaded are committed in another branch. Make sure you `git checkout` to that branch and search for what you want.

Comment: This answer solves my problem. I was trying to clone on the main branch but I need to clone on a different branch. I did the following steps.                                      
1. git branch (to check the current branch) 
2. git checkout <branch-name> (to switch to new branch)  
3. git clone <url>  
Now I was able to clone the code on my local.

Comment: Thank you!  In Visual 2022 after cloning simply switched to the correct branch (dropdown on the bottom right)