# After installing Git LFS - master (pre-receive hook declined)

Tags: git, github, hook, webhooks, git-lfs

**I know this question comes up a lot**, apologies for it... but I have read many entries here on StackOverflow but I have not been able to make any of them work. So here it comes once again, hoping to get some guidance...

Background: I am working alone in a project. I have always had my repo on GitHub and it has always worked well. Basically I did not have any problems pushing and pulling from the master. This time I had a large file +173MB so I decided to try the Git Large File Storage that always pops up. The process I followed is the one it says on the website:

```
brew install git-lfs
git lfs install
git lfs track "*.csv" (my file is a csv)
git add .gitattributes
```

After doing this, I was not able to push to the master anymore. The message is:

```
(venv-MBTI) (base) diego@DIGL Capstone 2 - MBTI % git push origin master
Uploading LFS objects: 100% (1/1), 345 B | 0 B/s, done.
Enumerating objects: 146, done.
Counting objects: 100% (135/135), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (116/116), done.
Writing objects: 100% (120/120), 59.90 MiB | 634.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 120 (delta 25), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (25/25), completed with 7 local objects.
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
remote: error: Trace: cb2e700c19f2bdbb2ca9aeb2df53605a
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File data/mbti_interim is 173.20 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
To https://github.com/DSJourney/MBTI.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/DSJourney/MBTI.git'
```

I tried most of the stuff I found in StackOverflow:

```
git pull --rebase
git reset --soft HEAD~1
git revert a2f2db2 (an older commit)
git push -u origin master
```

I also tried to follow

- the instructions from [here](http://Open%20your%20project%20%3E%20Settings%20%3E%20Repository%20and%20go%20to%20%22Protected%20branches%22,%20find%20%22master%22%20branch%20into%20the%20list%20and%20click%20%22Unprotect%22%20and%20try%20again.)
- the instructions from [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/protected_branches.html#restricting-push-and-merge-access-to-certain-users)

Other less relevant stuff

I guess I am doing something wrong, but have not been able to figure it out.

Any suggestion?

Comment: `File data/mbti_interim is 173.20 MB`. Try `git lfs track data/mbti_interim`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion ElpieKay, but it did not solve it, the same message pops up...

Comment: 1. Back up `data/mbti_interim`. If it has many versions, just clone the local repository to another path. 2. Remove `data/mbti_interim` from the history (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository). 3. Use `git lfs` to track `data/mbti_interim`.

Comment: Thanks ElpieKay, I think the problem was that there were many versions like you said. I had not seen your message so I went forward and deleted the GitHub repo and created a new one. Having looked at your suggestion it seem like that was the correct solution. Thanks for taking the time to deal with this.

Answer (score 0):

There were two proposed solutions, the right one was suggested by ElpieKay:

1. Back up `data/mbti_interim`. If it has many versions, just clone the local repository to another path.
2. Remove `data/mbti_interim` from the history ([LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229885/what-are-the-differences-between-gitignore-and-gitkeep))
3. Use `git lfs` to track `data/mbti_interim`

I had not seen that answer so my solution was to erase the GitHub repo altogether and start a new one without the file.