# How to test empty folders in Travis?

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, travis-ci

I'm working on a npm module that return content of folders.

I'm trying to test all possible use cases, and I want my tests to run on [Travis](https://travis-ci.org/).

I know git cannot handle empty folders, as described on this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767165/git-and-empty-folders), we typically have to put hidden files to store semi-empty folders on git.

But if I put an empty file in my folder, I'm testing a different use case, so I cannot follow this pattern. And neither I cannot run a script on Travis to create an empty folder, because 
the test would fail on my local machine.

Have you ever found yourself in a similar situation? How do you suggest me to handle this situation?

EDIT: I'm thinking to just add a files in empty folders, and to delete it at start of my test, but could be easy to do if someone knows a smarter way to do this.
Deletion of placeholder files is a little intricated, because at each test run on my development machine, they appear as an unstaged edit on my git status...

Answer (score 0):

I followed the intricate path.
In case it could be useful to someone in future, the code of the test [is on GitHub](https://github.com/parroit/webdisk/blob/master/test/webdisk_test.js).

And, just in the case that GitHub will be shutted down, and we are still alive despite the catastrophe, here is an extract of the code:

```
...

describe("webdisk", function() {

    before(function() {
        fs.unlinkSync("test/files/fold2/remove.this");
        fs.unlinkSync("test/only-folders/fold1/remove.this");
    });

    after(function() {
        fs.writeFileSync("test/files/fold2/remove.this", "remove.this");
        fs.writeFileSync("test/only-folders/fold1/remove.this", "remove.this");
    });

...
```

Initially it's a little ugly as I wrote it in a asynchronous way, rewritten as Louis suggested it's really improved.

Comment: Yes, ugly. Why use the asynchronous versions of ``fs.unlink`` and ``fs.writeFile`` in ``before`` and ``after``, rather than use the synchronous version of both calls?

Comment: Thank you, good suggestion. It's just the habit to use asynchronous, but in this case sync is better...